# Stop setinterval outside its function

Tags: jquery, setinterval

I have a function called 'sliderFunction' that starts a setInterval:

```
function sliderFunction() {

    var inter;

    function autoSlider() {
        var cur_img_div_pos = $('.img_slider.in_view').attr('data-pos');
        var num_img = $('.img_slider').length;
        var play_icon = $('#play_icon');

        play_icon.attr('data-active', '1');

        if (inter) {
            clearInterval(inter);
        }

        inter = setInterval(function(){         
            var pos = parseInt(cur_img_div_pos) + 1;
            var limit = parseInt(num_img) - 1;

            slider(pos, num_img);

            if (cur_img_div_pos < limit) {
                cur_img_div_pos++;
            } else {
                cur_img_div_pos = 0;
            }
            console.log(pos);
        }, 5000);
        console.log('start');
    }

    function stopSlider() {     
        var play_icon = $('#play_icon');
        var pause_icon = $('#pause_icon');
        var pause_active = pause_icon.attr('data-active');

        if (pause_active == 0) {
            play_icon.attr('data-active', '0');     
            pause_icon.attr('data-active', '1');
            clearInterval(inter);
            showButton('pause_icon');
            console.log('stop');
        }
    }

    function showButton(bt_id) {
        // bt_id -> pause_icon or play_icon
        var button = $('#' + bt_id);            
        button.fadeIn()
            .queue(function() {
                $(this).delay(1000).fadeOut().removeAttr('style');
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
    }

    var cur_img_div_pos = $('.img_slider.in_view').attr('data-pos');

    autoSlider(cur_img_div_pos);

    $(document).on('click', '.thumbs_anchor', function() {  
        if (inter) {
            stopSlider();
        }           
    });

    $(document).on('mouseenter', '.img_slider_inner', function() {  
        stopSlider();
    });

    $(document).on('mouseleave', '.img_slider_inner', function() {  
        var play_icon = $('#play_icon');
        var pause_icon = $('#pause_icon');          
        var play_active = play_icon.attr('data-active');

        if (play_active == 0) {
            play_icon.attr('data-active', '1');     
            pause_icon.attr('data-active', '0');
            autoSlider(cur_img_div_pos);
            showButton('play_icon');
        }
    });

}

sliderFunction();
```

Function 'stopSlider' works just fine because it is in the same function with 'autoSlider'. When I'm trying to execute 'clearInterval(inter)' outside 'sliderFunction', I get this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: inter is not defined
```

I tried make 'inter' global by leaving 'var' outside but I get an error when the function loads for the first time.

Any ideas?

Comment: A variable defined inside a function is only accessible inside that function. If you leave out the `var` keyword or use `window.inter = setInterval(...` is should be accesible everywhere as it's in the `window` scope (global).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove:

```
var inter;
```

and you're done. To be safe you can do this:

```
window.inter=null;
```

Comment: That moves the variable to global scope, which is a waste since everything currently is neatly tucked away in this sliderFunction.

Comment: @GolezTrol I know, but he was trying to global it, which is what I showed him how to do. Your answer is nicer though.

Comment: @kapantzak this does work, but I must admit this is somewhat poor practice. GolezTrol has a pretty good answer that works and is the best way of managing these kinds of things if you don't want hundreds of variables cluttering your global scope.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `inter` only exist inside the sliderFunction scope. Since both functions are in that scope, they both can reach that variable, but outside of sliderFunction you can't.

Solution? 
Change the declaration of stopSlider:

```
this.stopSlider = function() { 
 ...
```

Then, save the result of the sliderFunction function:

```
var slider = sliderFunction();
```

Now, you can use that result to call the function:

```
slider.stopSlider();
```

You've effectively turned sliderFunction into an object that has a method named stopSlider.